# Issues in executing JavaFX jar applet in Safari

Tags: java, safari, javafx-2

Following the instructions from [netbeans](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/javafx-setup.html), I could build JavaFX jar file.

[image]

The problem is that I can't execute the generated JavaFX applet in Safari web browser.

[image]

Firefox works fine.

[image]

Can Safari excute JavaFX?

I downloaded JavaFX 2.2 from [Java SE DK 7 site](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7u7-downloads-1836413.html).

Comment: Are you using Mountain Lion? (2.2 applets don't work in Safari on Mountain Lion - [known issue](http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-23529) fixed for the next JavaFX minor build - jdk7u10).

Comment: @jewelsea: I use Lion 10.7.4.

Comment: OK, I think your config should be [supported](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/downloads/supportedconfigurations-1506746.html).  Can you launch the [Ensemble sample](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/samples/index.html) in Safari?  Does the bit architecture ([32or64bit](http://www.ehow.com/how_5734712_run-safari-32bit.html)) of Safari match the bit architecture of the jdk?

Comment: @jewelsea: Ensemble sample works fine.

Comment: Hmm, then it is something different in how you packaged your app vs Ensemble, don't know what that is.  I guess compare your jnlp and html launch files with Ensemble's line by line and see if you can spot any differences which might cause issues . . .  If you still can't track it down, log a bug at http://javafx-jira.kenai.com with all relevant info and the JavaFX developers might look into it.

Comment: @jewelsea: Well, do you know how to download the Ensemble jnlp and jar file? I could download the html file with wget, but not the jnlp and jar files.

Comment: Yeah,  JavaFX demos and samples hosted on the same link you downloaded the jdk from in your question.